# Clicking on input element changes Installed Web App from "Standalone" to "Minimal-UI"

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications, manifest.json, html5-fullscreen

```
{
  "short_name": "My App",
  "name": "My Application",
  "background_color": "#ff9800",
  "theme_color": "#ff9800",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-256x256-icon.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-512x512-icon.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/MyApp/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

This is my `manifest.json` file which is working fine.  I can install the app from Chrome on Android and launch it from the home screen.  The splash screen shows up and the app is in `Standalone` mode (Status bar shows but not browser toolbar).

However, when I click on an input (text input, button, etc.), the web app shifts to `Minimal-UI` mode (minimal browser toolbar shows).  I don't know why.

On refresh it fixes it.

Comment: does clicking on those components result in navigation ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody No it doesn't.